# Zip a file in clojure

Tags: clojure, zip

I want to zip a file in clojure and I can't find any libraries to do it.

Do you know a good way to zip a file or a folder in Clojure?
Must I use a java library?

Comment: Just curious, why do you not want to use a Java library? Using existing java libs is one of the biggest USPs of clojure and other JVM based languages. Why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: I thought use an existing library... I don't understand your answer. Maybe my english is bad... What is USP ?

Comment: @jeremieca [USP = Unique selling proposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unique_selling_proposition)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There is a stock `ZipOutputStream` in Java which can be used from Clojure. I don't know whether there is a library somewhere. I use the plain Java functions with a small helper macro:

```
(defmacro ^:private with-entry
  [zip entry-name & body]
  `(let [^ZipOutputStream zip# ~zip]
     (.putNextEntry zip# (ZipEntry. ~entry-name))
     ~@body
     (flush)
     (.closeEntry zip#)))
```

Obviously every ZIP entry describes a file.

```
(require '[clojure.java.io :as io])

(with-open [file (io/output-stream "foo.zip")
            zip  (ZipOutputStream. file)
            wrt  (io/writer zip)]
  (binding [*out* wrt]
    (doto zip
      (with-entry "foo.txt"
        (println "foo"))
      (with-entry "bar/baz.txt"
        (println "baz")))))
```

To zip a file you might want to do something like this:

```
(with-open [output (ZipOutputStream. (io/output-stream "foo.zip"))
            input  (io/input-stream "foo")]
  (with-entry output "foo"
    (io/copy input output)))
```

Comment: Thanks ! And the import for ZipOutputStream is : `(:import [java.util.zip ZipOutputStream])`.

Comment: Or just `(:import java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream)`.

Comment: Yes... Because I forgot ZipEntry : `(:import [java.util.zip ZipEntry ZipOutputStream])`

Answer (score 3):

All compression and decompression of files can be done with a simple shell command which we can access through `clojure.java.shell`

Using the same method you can also compress and decompress any compression type you would usually from your terminal.

```
(use '[clojure.java.shell :only [sh]])


(defn unpack-resources [in out]
  (clojure.java.shell/sh 
   "sh" "-c" 
  (str " unzip " in " -d " out)))

(defn pack-resources [in out]
  (clojure.java.shell/sh 
   "sh" "-c" 
  (str " zip " in " -r " out)))

(unpack-resources "/path/to/my/zip/foo.zip" 
                  "/path/to/store/unzipped/files")

(pack-resources "/path/to/store/archive/myZipArchiveName.zip" 
                "/path/to/my/file/myTextFile.csv")
```

Comment: When using files that are Java objects and look like:
`#object[java.io.File 0x4d541cba "/tmp/7bbfdfaf-8b00-4bdc-b7c2-bc270d6564b4.zip"]`, the `str` changes them into a mere string with only `"/tmp/7bbfdfaf-8b00-4bdc-b7c2-bc270d6564b4.zip"` in it, and the function fails with `file not found` error. 

What would you suggest for a case like this?

Answer (score 0):

You can import this (gzip) https://gist.github.com/bpsm/1858654
Its quite interesting.
Or more precisely, you can use this

```
(defn gzip    
[input output & opts]
(with-open [output (-> output clojure.java.io/output-stream GZIPOutputStream.)]
 (with-open [rdr (clojure.java.io/reader input)]
  (doall (apply clojure.java.io/copy rdr output opts)))))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [rtcritical/clj-ant-tasks](https://github.com/rtcritical/clj-ant-tasks) library that wraps [Apache Ant](https://ant.apache.org/), and zip with a single command.

Add library dependency [rtcritical/clj-ant-tasks "1.0.1"]

```
(require '[rtcritical.clj-ant-tasks :refer [run-ant-task]])
```

To zip a file:

```
(run-ant-task :zip {:destfile "/tmp/file-zipped.zip" 
                    :basedir "/tmp"
                    :includes "file-to-zip"})
```

Note: run-ant-task(s) functions in this library namespace can be used to run any other [Apache Ant](https://ant.apache.org/) task(s) as well.

For more information, see [https://github.com/rtcritical/clj-ant-tasks](http://%20https://github.com/rtcritical/clj-ant-tasks)